# "The product of two prime numbers is not abundant" proof by contradiction

Tags: number-theory, alternative-proof

[An abundant number is a positive integer $n$ whose divisors add up to
more than $2n$. For example, $12$ is abundant because $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 + 12 > 24$.]

There is a theorem that states that: " The product of two distinct primes is not abundant". Here is a proof. [Found here: https://www.lboro.ac.uk/media/media/schoolanddepartments/mathematics-education-centre/downloads/research/SE-booklet.pdf]

[image]

I am puzzled how one can proved this theorem by contradiction. Thanks in  advance for any help.

Comment: You have shown that the product is either deficient or perfect. Hence you are done. A contradiction proof would just disprove the inequality in the other direction, so your proof can also be used as a contradiction proof.

Comment: @Peter Thanks a lot. In fact, one arrives at $$3\geq \frac{1+p_1}{1-p_1}\geq p_2$$ which violates one of the hypotheses.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand the assumption in the second line. You already said they can't equal one another. If p1 equals 3 and P2 equals 2, don't you get the same results?

4/2 is less than or equal to 2.

The assumption seems to make you want to say there must be an ordering of the primes and that is just not true. Because the max is always 3 no matter the order. And that is what the proof is using.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).